# css class attribute do not work with html code generated with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have this javascript function that inserts dynamically a table content, i want to use a css class class="info" for my inserted rows but it does not work.
i am new to javascript and i don't know what is going wrong with my code.

```
function getPositions() {
    $.ajax({
        dataType : 'json',
        contentType : 'application/json',
        url : 'positions',
            success: function(data) {  
                var table = $('#datatable').DataTable();
                table.clear().draw();
                var rowNode= new Array();
                for (var key=0, size=data.length; key<size; key++){
                    var j = -1;
                    var r = new Array()
                    r[++j] = '<tr class="info"><td >'+data[key].id+'</td>';       
                    r[++j] = '<td>'+data[key].id_sec_account+'</td>';
                    r[++j] = '<td>'+ data[key].id_sec+'</td>';
                    r[++j] = '<td>'+ data[key].quantity+ '</td>';
                    r[++j] = '<td>'+ data[key].status+ '</td>';
                    r[++j] ='</tr>'; 
                    rowNode = table.row.add(r);
                }
            rowNode.draw().node()
            }
        });
    }
setInterval(getPositions, 3000);
```

Comment: What do you mean "it does not work"? Adding `class="info"` to the `tr`? Did you write any CSS? what does the rendered HTML look like?

Comment: the class content is provided by a bootstrap template, i have used it in other tables with data created without ajax and it works perfectly, actually this class sets the color of the row to blue. in my case, where the table is filled with javascript code, adding the class attribute does not have any effect on my rows

Answer (score 0):

your table should have class `.table` first. Then only `.info` class will work on the row.